# How to execute a remote command over ssh with arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

In my `.bashrc` I define a function which I can use on the command line later:

```
function mycommand() {
    ssh user@123.456.789.0 cd testdir;./test.sh "$1"
}
```

When using this command, just the `cd` command is executed on the remote host; the `test.sh` command is executed on the local host. This is because the semicolon separates two different commands: the `ssh` command and the `test.sh` command.

I tried defining the function as follows (note the single quotes):

```
function mycommand() {
    ssh user@123.456.789.0 'cd testdir;./test.sh "$1"'
}
```

I tried to keep the `cd` command and the `test.sh` command together, but the argument `$1` is not resolved, independent of what I give to the function. It is always tried to execute a command

```
./test.sh $1
```

on the remote host.

How do I properly define `mycommand`, so the script `test.sh` is executed on the remote host after changing into the directory `testdir`, with the ability to pass on the argument given to `mycommand` to `test.sh`?

Comment: This is unrelated to the main point, but you might want to use `&&` instead of the semi-colon to join the commands executed on the remote host:  `cd testdir && ./test.sh "$1"`.  With that form (because evaluation of `&&` short-circuits in bash), if the `cd` fails the second command won't be executed, and you won't inadvertently run a different `test.sh` in `user`'s homedir.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Do it this way instead:

```
function mycommand {
    ssh user@123.456.789.0 "cd testdir;./test.sh \"$1\""
}
```

You still have to pass the whole command as a single string, yet in that single string you need to have `$1` expanded before it is sent to ssh so you need to use `""` for it.

#### Update

Another proper way to do this actually is to use `printf %q` to properly quote the argument. This would make the argument safe to parse even if it has spaces, single quotes, double quotes, or any other character that may have a special meaning to the shell:

```
function mycommand {
    printf -v __ %q "$1"
    ssh user@123.456.789.0 "cd testdir;./test.sh $__"
}
```

- When declaring a function with `function`, `()` is not necessary.
- Don't comment back about it just because you're a POSIXist.

Starting Bash version 4.4, it can also be simplified to this:

```
function mycommand {
    ssh user@123.456.789.0 "cd testdir;./test.sh ${1@Q}"
}
```

See `${parameter@operator}` section in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: @JoSo Yes that's the basic of it so depending on usage the user can opt to sanitize the argument he needs it. With respect to basic `ssh` there's probably no better way - unless you do file transfers first, etc.

Comment: @JoSo Yes, a better approach would be to define a quote function like `quote() { printf "'%q'" "$1"; }`, and then do `ssh user@host "cd testdir; ./test.sh $(quote "$1")"`

Comment: @augurar, almost, but `%q` results are self-quoting; surrounding them with literal quotes isn't necessary or correct. `printf -v arg_str '%q ' "$1"; ssh user@host "cd testdir; ./test.sh $arg_str"` suffices.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why do you need to add space though?

Comment: @konsolebox, for just the immediate case, don't really, but that way the idiom scales if more arguments are added rather than smushing them all together.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good catch, that's a typo.  Should be `printf "%q" "$1"`.

Answer (score 13):

This is an example that works on the AWS Cloud. The scenario is that some machine that booted from autoscaling needs to perform some action on another server, passing the newly spawned instance DNS via SSH

```
# Get the public DNS of the current machine (AWS specific)
MY_DNS=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname`


ssh \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
    user@remotehost.example.com \
<< EOF
cd ~/
echo "Hey I was just SSHed by ${MY_DNS}"
run_other_commands
# Newline is important before final EOF!

EOF
```

Answer (score 13):

**Solution**: you want to be able connect to machine remotely using ssh protocol and trigger/run some actions outside.

on ssh use a `-t` flag, from documentation:

> `-t  Force pseudo-terminal allocation.`
> `This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g.`
> `when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.`

**formula**:

```
ssh -i <key-path> <user>@<remote-machine> -t '<action>'
```

**Example**: as administrator I want to be able to connect remotely into ec2 machines and trigger a revert process for a bad deployment on a several machines in a raw, moreover you better implement this action as an automation script that use ips as an arguments and running on different machines in parallel.

```
ssh -i /home/admin/.ssh/key admin@10.20.30.40 -t 'cd /home/application && make revert'
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm using the following to execute commands on the remote from my local computer:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/$GIT_PRIVKEY user@$IP "bash -s" < localpath/script.sh $arg1 $arg2
```

Comment: the script is remote not local

Answer (score -3):

A little trick for me, using the "bash -s" they said they allow POSITIONAL ARGS but apparently the $0 is already reserved for whatever reason... Then using twice the same args rocks like so:

```
ssh user@host "bash -s" < ./start_app.sh -e test -e test -f docker-compose.services.yml
```

Comment: the script is remote not local