# Trigger perl scripts remotely on windows

Tags: windows, perl, ssh, remote-server

I have two machines A and B. Machine B has perl installed and scripts are placed in a shared directory. Machine A doesn't have perl installed (I don't want to install perl on this machine). There is some automation running in Machine A and that automation wants to trigger perl scripts in Machine B by passing some parameters.

Is this possible? What is recommended?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502945/how-to-execute-a-remote-command-over-ssh-with-arguments ?

Comment: If it's not important that the Perl scripts run *on* Machine B, but instead that the Perl scripts *residing on* Machine B be run by *any* Machine, then you can share the Perl scripts and the Perl install from Machine B, and run them from any remote Machine that can access the fileshare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably more possibilites, but from the top of my head:

- Mark Russinovich's [`psexec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) ([notes@ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html))
- the Windows Management Instrumentation Commandline tool [`wmic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([notes@ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html))

As long as the machine on which the perl scripts are to be executed has perl installed, it's not a problem if the caller machine doesn't.