# How to access different container from nginx container in Docker?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have build docker environment for my laravel application. I am running app in `nginx` container with `php-fpm` configured.

My question is how can I access another containers that I have defined in `docker-compose.yml` from `nginx container`?

For example I want to connect `libreoffice` container that I have created in docker, from my app which is running in `nginx` container. If I run some command in my app it is getting executed in `nginx` container.

Let's say I execute `soffice ...` it will throw an error that `soffice not found`. Because `soffice` is not installed in `nginx` container. It is installed as docker image.

Then How can I access to `libreoffice` container from `nginx` container? Should I install `libreoffice` service to `nginx` container in `Dockerfile` or run 2 services in single container? I am really confused

**Edit:**

*docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  # LibreOffice Service
  libreoffice:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/libreoffice:latest
    container_name: libreoffice
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

*Controller*:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WordToPdfController extends Controller {

    public function convert(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'document' => 'required|file|mimes:docx,doc'
        ]);

        $document = $request->file('document');

        $extension = $request->file('document')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = str_replace(".$extension",'', $document->getClientOriginalName());

        $document->move("tmp", $document->getClientOriginalName());





        // Main part is here



        $command = "soffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf --outdir \"tmp\" \"tmp/$fileName.$extension\"";
        $result = $this->exec($command);






        sleep(1);

        if(!empty($result['stderr'])) {
            throw new \Exception("tmp/$fileName.$extension: ".$result['stderr']);
        }

        if(!@filesize('tmp/'.$fileName.'.pdf')) {
            $this->convert($request);
        }

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '.pdf"');
        header("Content-length: " . filesize('tmp/'.$fileName.'.pdf'));
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        flush();
        readfile('tmp/'.$fileName.'.pdf');
        unlink('tmp/'.$fileName.'.pdf');
        unlink('tmp/'.$fileName.'.'.$extension);
        exit;
    }
}
```

I am able to run application but when is comes to running command it throws error that:

```
`soffice not found`
```

Because the command getting running in `nginx` container and there is not `soffice` installed. Soffice (which is libreoffice service) running as another container in docker. Then how can I run the command in nginx container to access `libreoffice` service that is running on same host with port `3000` (check `docker-compose.yml`  file)?

Comment: What is the actual issue you're trying to solve? Why do you need to start apps in a container manually and moreover from another container?

Comment: each container/service is like a separate computer. You can't run programs on a different computer just by invoking them. They need to expose an API that you can reach through a call to IP:PORT. And then you can make an appropriate call to that api and get the "remote" service to do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Mihai Yes you are right. If libreoffice doesn't have any `API` then in my case it is impossible to do with different containers yes? I should actually install this service in `nginx` container and run command there.

Comment: You can run command remotely using ssh. You only have to make sure that you have established some extra stuff for your containers (keys, etc). Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502945/how-to-execute-a-remote-command-over-ssh-with-arguments) regarding calling remote command.

Comment: I wouldn't go the ssh way. it'a a dirty workaround. Instead try to search the web for "libreoffice rest api". I see there are  quite a few implementations. maybe you find something. I also see already made docker images for libreoffice - check how they are used.