# ssh remote execution in bash script inside variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to put following in a bash script:

`ssh hostname "rm -rf ~/directory"`

The above run successfully.

When I put it in a script like following, it does works:

```
#!bash

SSH_HOST=hostname
DIR_REMOTE='~/directory'

ssh $SSH_HOST "rm -rf $DIR_REMOTE"
```

However, when I try to encapsulate the whole command in a variable, it does not work:

```
#!bash

SSH_HOST=hostname
DIR_REMOTE='~/directory'

CMD="ssh $SSH_HOST \"rm -rf $DIR_REMOTE\""
echo "$CMD"
$CMD
```

It gives following error:

`zsh:1: no such file or directory: rm -rf ~/directory`

What am I doing wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Storing commands in variables is almost always a bad idea; the way they're expanded is weird. Store executable code in functions, not variables (or don't store it at all, just execute it). See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia), and the many other questions linked from that one.

Comment: You do not use `bash` but `zsh`.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502945/how-to-execute-a-remote-command-over-ssh-with-arguments

Comment: @Cyrus `zsh` is the remote host shell, my script is `bash`.

Comment: @LéaGris Similar, but not the same, actually the solution is opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version of the script, your local bash interpreter is removing the quotes before `ssh` is run, so

```
ssh $SSH_HOST "rm -rf $DIR_REMOTE"
```

and

```
ssh $SSH_HOST rm -rf $DIR_REMOTE
```

do exactly the same thing -- you're passing `rm -rf ~/directory` to `$SSH_HOST` via ssh.

When you run

```
CMD="ssh $SSH_HOST \"rm -rf $DIR_REMOTE\""
echo "$CMD"
$CMD
```

the bash interpreter is removing the first set of quotes, and you're passing the quoted string `"rm -rf ~/directory"` to `$SSH_HOST` via ssh. The remote shell (in this case `zsh`) is trying to execute the file `"rm -rf ~/directory"`, and cannot, so it's throwing an error message.

If you leave off the inner quotes:

```
CMD="ssh $SSH_HOST rm -rf $DIR_REMOTE"
echo "$CMD"
$CMD
```

You will be sending the unquoted string `rm -rf ~/directory` via ssh, and `zsh` will interpret it correctly.

---

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, running code from variables, while possible, is brittle and likely to be insecure; as such, it's considered bad practice. Variables are for data, functions are for code.

As such, you're much better off writing a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

remove_remote_dir() {
    local SSH_HOST=$1
    local DIR_REMOTE=$2

    ssh $SSH_HOST "rm -rf $DIR_REMOTE"
}

remove_remote_dir hostname '~/directory'
```

Comment: While your answer may work for this special case; it does not help @johnsiu learn better practices with placing code in a function. Also expanding `$DIR_REMOTE` as-is without properly escaping and securing its content; is creating a remote code execution vulnerability.

Comment: @LéaGris I know doing it this way is a mess. But this is for a small script from my own use, so the risk is minimum.